# Every file in <head></head> being checked by htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I noticed from my htaccess log files, that every file included in my webpage's `<head></head>` section is also being checked for.

Is this normal behavior, or am I missing something? I don't see why these need to be checked. It's unnecessary.

In the log below, every `.js` and `.css` file is mentioned and checked for, which is unnecessary. How do I stop this from happening or is this the way it is?

This is not all, there's a lot more I did not paste here.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:09:34:52 +051800] [test.com/sid#7e48f0][rid#1849050/initial] (3) [perdir C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/site/scripts/testFramework.js -> site/scripts/testFramework.js
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:09:34:52 +051800] [test.com/sid#7e48f0][rid#1849050/initial] (3) [perdir C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'site/scripts/testFramework.js'
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:09:34:52 +051800] [test.com/sid#7e48f0][rid#1849050/initial] (1) [perdir C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/] pass through C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/site/scripts/testFramework.js
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:09:34:52 +051800] [test.com/sid#7e48f0][rid#18f10d0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/site/scripts/testCore.js -> site/scripts/testCore.js
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:09:34:52 +051800] [test.com/sid#7e48f0][rid#18f10d0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'site/scripts/testCore.js'
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:09:34:52 +051800] [test.com/sid#7e48f0][rid#18f10d0/initial] (1) [perdir C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/] pass through C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/site/scripts/testCore.js
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:09:34:52 +051800] [test.com/sid#7e48f0][rid#1851070/initial] (3) [perdir C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/site/scripts/testValidate.js -> site/scripts/testValidate.js
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:09:34:52 +051800] [test.com/sid#7e48f0][rid#1851070/initial] (3) [perdir C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'site/scripts/testValidate.js'
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:09:34:52 +051800] [test.com/sid#7e48f0][rid#1851070/initial] (1) [perdir C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/] pass through C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/site/scripts/testValidate.js
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:09:34:52 +051800] [test.com/sid#7e48f0][rid#1849050/initial] (3) [perdir C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/site/css/style.css -> site/css/style.css
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:09:34:52 +051800] [test.com/sid#7e48f0][rid#1849050/initial] (3) [perdir C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'site/css/style.css'
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:09:34:52 +051800] [test.com/sid#7e48f0][rid#1849050/initial] (1) [perdir C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/] pass through C:/web/apache/htdocs/test/site/css/style.css
```

Comment: Can you show your latest .htaccess in your question?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal and it doesn't add much overhead for your server anyway.
One thing you can do to minimize the "problem" is to put all your assets in one specific folder (not a child of the folder where your actual php/html/whatever are located), then create one `<Directory>` section in your `httpd.conf` for each folder where the assets folder get minimum checks and your web site URLs can still have more complex rules applied only for them.

Read more about this [**here**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory).

Comment: I put a .htaccess file with RewriteEngine Off in the folder and now it does not check anything there. But is this method ok?

Comment: @Norman you put the `.htaccess` file in a folder that have only assets (images, css, etc)? If yes that's okay :)

Comment: Yes, I put it in the folder containing the js and css files and images.